# Enabling batch contextual actions in a ListView without long-click

Tags: android, listview, actionmode

I have a ListView with a MultiChoiceModeListener to delete items. At the moment, the action mode is started when a long-click is performed on a item. This is working fine but, in addition, I want to allow the user enable the action mode when they click on a "Edit" button.

Is there a way to enable this mode without a long-click?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CABforViews

Basically:

1. Implement the `ActionMode.Callback` interface
2. Call `startActionMode()` manually on button click

An example CommonsWare project that might help: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionMode/Manual